# Has Tez support been removed from Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

Attempting to build 1.3.1 with (out of date) https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.9/setup/flink_on_tez.html instructions yielded:

mvn  -DskipTests clean package -Pinclude-tez -Dhadoop.version=2.7.1 -Dtez.version=0.7.0

[WARNING] The requested profile "include-tez" could not be activated because it does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it was removed quite some time ago.